# Scaling issues in plotly, R programing

Tags: r, plotly, contour, r-plotly

I have a matrix with `NA` values on the y-axis at the “0.75” point, but when I plot the contour plot, the blank area of the graph comes up at the “10” and “10.75” point.

I am pretty sure it is because of my scaling in my axis (which I have done using a specified equation from [plotly](/questions/tagged/plotly)), but don’t know where I am going wrong. The other blank areas in the [contour](/questions/tagged/contour) plot are correct and are `NA` values.

Here is the dataframe, WW3_MF

```
   V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6   V7   V8   V9  V10
   NA -1.5 -1.0 -1.0   NA  0.5 -1.0 -1.0 -1.5 -3.0
   NA -1.5 -1.0 -0.5  0.0  1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -2.0 -4.0
   NA -1.5 -1.0 -1.0  1.0   NA  0.0 -1.0 -2.5 -4.5
   NA -1.5 -1.0 -1.0   NA  1.5   NA -1.0 -3.0 -4.5
   NA -1.0 -1.0 -0.5  1.0  1.5 -1.0 -1.0 -2.5 -4.5
   NA -1.5 -2.0 -0.5  1.0  2.0 -2.0 -1.0 -3.0 -5.0
   NA -1.5 -2.0 -0.5  0.5  1.5 -2.0 -1.5 -3.0 -4.5
   NA -1.5 -2.0 -1.0 -0.5  1.5 -2.5 -1.0 -3.0 -4.5
   NA -0.5 -1.0   NA  1.0   NA -3.5 -1.0 -3.0 -4.5
   NA -0.5 -1.5 -1.0  0.0  2.5 -3.5  0.0 -3.0 -4.5
   NA -1.0 -1.0 -0.5 -0.5  2.5   NA -0.5 -3.0 -5.5
   NA -0.5 -1.5  0.5 -1.0  3.0 -4.0  0.5 -2.5 -5.0
   NA -0.5 -1.0 -0.5 -1.5  3.0 -4.5  0.5 -2.5 -5.0
   NA -0.5 -1.5 -0.5   NA  2.5 -3.5  0.0 -2.5 -4.5
   NA  0.0 -1.0   NA -2.0  3.0 -2.5 -0.5 -2.5 -4.0
   NA  0.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.5  3.5 -3.0  0.5 -3.0 -4.0
   NA  0.5 -0.5 -1.5   NA  2.5 -2.0  0.5 -2.5 -4.0
   NA  0.5  0.5  0.5 -1.0  2.5 -1.0  1.0 -2.0 -4.0
   NA  0.5  0.5  0.5 -1.0  3.0 -1.0  1.0 -2.0 -3.5
   NA -1.0  0.5  0.0  0.5  2.0 -0.5  0.5 -2.0 -3.5
   NA  0.5  1.0  0.5  0.5  2.0  0.5  0.5 -1.5 -3.5
   NA  0.5  0.5 -0.5  0.0  1.5  0.5  1.0 -1.5 -3.0
   NA  0.5  0.5 -0.5   NA  1.0  0.5  0.0 -1.0 -3.0
   NA  0.5  0.0 -1.5 -1.0 -0.5   NA -1.0 -2.0 -3.0
   NA  1.0  0.5 -1.0 -1.0  0.5 -0.5 -1.0 -2.0 -2.5
   NA  1.0 -0.5 -1.0 -1.0  0.0  0.5 -1.5 -1.5 -3.0
   NA  1.0  0.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.5 -2.0 -3.0
   NA  1.5  1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -0.5 -1.0 -1.5 -2.0 -3.0
   NA  0.5  0.5 -1.0 -1.5 -1.0 -2.0 -2.0 -3.0 -3.5
   NA  0.5  0.5 -1.0 -1.5 -1.0 -2.0 -2.0 -3.0 -3.0
   NA  0.0 -0.5 -1.0 -2.0 -1.5 -2.5 -2.0 -3.5 -3.0
   NA -0.5 -0.5 -1.5 -2.0 -1.5 -2.5 -2.0 -4.0 -3.0
   NA -0.5 -0.5 -1.5 -2.0 -1.5 -2.5 -2.5 -4.0 -3.5
   NA -0.5 -1.0 -1.5 -2.0 -1.5 -2.5 -2.5 -4.0 -3.5
   NA  0.5 -0.5 -1.0 -1.5 -1.0 -2.0 -2.0 -4.0 -3.0
   NA  0.5 -1.0 -1.0 -1.5 -1.5 -3.0 -2.0 -5.0 -3.0
   NA  0.5  0.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -2.5 -2.0 -5.0 -3.0
   NA  0.5  0.5 -1.0 -1.5 -1.5 -3.0 -2.0 -5.0 -3.0
   NA  0.5 -0.5 -1.0 -1.0 -1.5 -3.5 -1.5 -4.5 -3.0
   NA  1.0  0.5 -1.0 -1.0 -2.5 -3.0 -2.0 -4.5 -3.5
   NA  1.5 -0.5 -1.5 -1.0 -2.0 -3.0 -1.5 -3.5 -3.5
   NA  1.5 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -2.0 -3.0 -1.0 -3.0 -3.5
   NA  1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.5 -2.5 -3.0 -1.0 -3.0 -3.0
   NA  1.5 -0.5 -1.0 -1.0 -3.0 -2.5 -1.0 -2.5 -3.0
   NA  1.0 -1.5 -1.0 -1.5 -3.0 -3.0 -1.5 -4.0 -2.5
```

Here is my `R`-script.

```
p <- plot_ly(z = matrix(c(WW3_MF)),  type="contour", width=500,   height=1074, colorbar = list(title = "Accumulation/Erosion (cm)"), 
         colorscale=list (c(0, "rgb(0,0,255)"),list(0.65, "rgb(135,206,250)"), list(0.75, "rgb(255,255,0)"), list(0.85, "rgb(255,165,0)"), list(1, "rgb(255,0,0)")),zauto=F, zmin=-14, zmax=8) %>%
layout(title="WW3_MF", 

yaxis=list(title="Y(m)", tickmode = "array",ticktext = c("-0.75", "-0.1", "0.1", "0.5","1.5", "2.5", "5", "7.5", "10", "10.75"),tickvals = c("1", "1.51", "1.67", "1.98","2.76", "3.54", "5.5", "7.46", "9.41", "10"),range = c(1,10)), 

xaxis=list(nticks="4",title="X(m)",tickmode = "array",ticktext = c("1", "2", "3"),tickvals = c("15", "30", "45"),range=0,45), shapes =list(type = "rect",line = list(color = "black"), x0 = "0", x1 = "22.5", xref = "x",y0 = "0.58", y1 = "8.41", yref = "y"))
(contours = list(z =list(show=TRUE, usecolormap=TRUE,highlightcolor="#ffA500",project=list,countourlabels="TRUE")))
    (scene = list(camera=list(eye = list(x=1.87, y=0.88, z=-0.64))))p
```

Here is the `contour plot`.

[image: WW3_MF, contour plot]

Here is the second contour plot with a range (0,9) and tickvals = c("0", "0.509", "0.665", "0.978","1.761", "2.543", "4.5", "6.457", "8.413", "9")

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you provide the WW3_MF dataset? Without the data/a [MCVE] it is hard to help.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking a interest. I have put the dataframe in the question, sorry about that it took me while to work out the best way. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the update! Is the `contours ` and `scene` brackets part of the code?

Comment: Yes, I edited the script, I hope this is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if I understood your question correctly but here is a guess.

The blank space you are seeing on top of your graph is not coming from your `NA` values but because there are "no" values in your data frame.
You specify the `range` for your y-axis going from 1 to 10, but the data actually starts at 0 and goes to 9.

If you set `range = c(0, 9)` the data should be correctly plotted. Try changing some of the `NA` in the first row and you should see a difference.

In addition `tickvals` is provided as an array of strings, not numbers/floats. Since you don't have a linear scale, Plotly "mis"interprets the underlying data. Try removing the ticks around the numbers and the numbers should look better.

Comment: I think from your answer, it seems that you understand what I am trying to do, but should I explain it more. This sounded like a logical answer. Your answer sounded really logical and I tried it and it worked. But now I get allot of blank space where there should be values. I have attached the new plot to the original question.  Thanks!

Comment: I updated the answer. The observed blank space is probably because of `tickvals`.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the late answer. I took out the ticks but this did not change the graph. However your answer gave me a hint. Having thought about this I think the problem is my values in the matrix, are not consecutive. For example, plotly is assuming V1=0, V2=1, V3=2 and so on, so puts the values for these data points at these points. But my actual values (where the data was taken) are V1=-0.1, V2=0.1, V3=0.75 and so on. So the large gap I am seeing is V1=1 but it goes over my -0.1-0.75 range, so it looks like a larger section is missing. However I am not sure how to solve this.